# add a numeric variable from a data.frame object to an sf object containing multpolygons

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I'm unable to add a numeric variable in a data frame object to an SF object containing polygons. So, I can't create my map with Ggplot2.

Any help would be very appreciated...

Thanks a lot

Richard

Comment: Hi Richard, without seeing the data and the code you are using, your question is impossible to answer. Please try to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 4):

The `{sf}` objects are modified data frames. There is one column, usually the last, that contains geometry and is mostly hidden + there is some special sauce about coordinate reference systems and so on. But the gist is a data frame (unlike the earlier `{sp}` objects, but I digress).

As such the `{sf}` data frames lend themselves easily to data joining techniques, such as `dplyr::left_join()` used in code example below.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) # included with sf package

# just some semi - random data
# county with ID 2041 is Mecklenburg (as in Charlotte of Mecklenburg-Strelitz)
some_values <- data.frame(ID = c(2041),
                          value = c(1))

# left is usually safer than inner join as it does not filter rows
mod_shape <- shape %>% 
  left_join(some_values, by = c("CNTY_ID" = "ID")) 

ggplot(data = mod_shape) +
   geom_sf(aes(fill = value))  # viola! a polygon of North Carolina
```

[image: NC shapefile with Mecklenburg cnty in blue]